# JsRender+JsViews select databinding

Tags: jquery, data-binding, jsrender

Here is the link to jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0ojrq2px/15/
Somehow that `Is Lead?` values dropdown is not getting initial value.. am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Your are using JsRender. Using data-link, to get data-binding on the `<select>`, needs JsViews, with the `link()` method, (not just JsRender with the `render()` method).

- https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvlinktmpl
- https://www.jsviews.com/#link-select

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using - https://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.min.js which includes JsRender, observable and JsViews. Is that enough or I'm missing something here?

Comment: just updated $(document).ready function with needed changes but the result hasn't changed :(

Comment: I tried binding select with json model, it works. The described situation above is with props iteration where that binding doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: First thing is too study the docs, as well as the examples. For example, it explains that you need to bind tags using `{^{props ...}}` when doing data-binding. Worst case if you still really have a problem -  create a jsfiddle working example, as minimalistic as possible. Just the thing you are doing that does not seem to work, so people can see exactly what you are doing. (For example your code above had errors like unmatched HTML tags etc. You need to be sure that obvious errors have been eliminated, before asking folks to look at your code.)